# What do each of these stand for after the "Save file?" prompt: (y, n, !, ., q, C-r, d or C-h)

Tags: emacs

The question is pretty self-explanatory. When I close emacs and some changes are unsaved, I'm asked if I want to save the file and given this list of options. I assume "y" and "n" are "yes" and "no", but what are the other options?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Type <kbd>?</kbd> and you'll get a buffer showing:

```
Type SPC or `y' to save the current buffer;
DEL or `n' to skip the current buffer;
RET or `q' to give up on the save (skip all remaining buffers);
C-g to quit (cancel the whole command);
! to save all remaining buffers;
C-r to view this buffer;
d to view changes in this buffer;
or . (period) to save the current buffer and exit.
```

If you want to add/change actions that happen during the `save-some-buffers` function, then you can modify the variable `save-some-buffers-action-alist`.  Perhaps if you wanted to add a binding to save the changes and kill the buffer via the key <kbd>k</kbd>.  You could do this:

```
(add-to-list 'save-some-buffers-action-alist
             `(?k ,(lambda (buf) (save-buffer buf) (kill-buffer buf))
                  ,(purecopy "save changes and kill the buffer")))
```

If you look at the documentation for `save-some-buffers`, it will direct you to `save-some-buffers-action-alist` - which further directs you to `map-y-or-n-p` - which actually does have [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Multiple-Queries.html) on the format of that variable.

Comment: Or indeed `C-h`, as suggested in the original message. That is always some kind of *Help* binding, so when it suggests it as one of the options, there's a fair chance that it's going to answer any questions you have about the others.

Comment: This behavior is particularly annoying when re-compiling. If I don't care at all about this buffer I might as well close it. But if I C-r to view it, I can't get out of the modeline to close it. I need to C-g the compile command, search in my buffers and then close it. Anyone has a workaround ?

Comment: @Aaron cancel the quit?  You can just initiate the exit command again.  Once you've quit the command, there's no way to resume.